# Subaru WRX is making a flutter sound?

Tags: engine, noise, subaru, wrx

I have a 2017 Subaru WRX and it’s making like a fluttering sound At idle but as soon as I push on the clutch it goes away and then when I’m driving the sound comes back. I’m not sure what it could be this is my first car that I’m working on and I don’t know much and I need help identifying the problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You say the noise goes away when you push on the clutch pedal. How much force does it take for the noise to go away? If you just push the clutch pedal in enough to take up the slack, does the noise go away? Or is it when the pedal is all the way to the floor?

Comment: Sounds like a possible clutch or clutch mechanism issue.  How many miles on the car?  What kind of driving do you do?

Answer (score -1):

It could be the clutch thrust bearing .Probably not an expensive part .I have not worked on subaru  but somebody should be able to estimate labour which is bound to exceed the parts .